# C++ Chess Engine - (Magic)Bitboard-based move generation

Tags: c++, c++17, bitwise, chess

I am currently writing a bitboard-based Chess Engine in C++, and I recently finished the move generation. I am using move-lookup-tables that get pre-calculated at application startup for sliding and non-sliding pieces. For the sliding pieces I implemented magic bitboards, which get handled in the `MagicBitboards` class (should be pretty irrelevant here, so I did not include them in the question).

The move generator now successfully passes multiple `perft()` test positions, but it is still pretty slow and I feel like the implementation is all over the place code-wise (and much longer than it should probably be). I tried to summarize and generalize functions as much as possible, but somehow there always is a justification for all the extra functions to exist on their own (most of the time, I feel like the code would just get completely un-readable if I packed more similar but different functionality in the same function).

Most of the CPU calls get wasted in the `check_for_legality()` function, because everything else is basically just looking up moves in pre-calculated arrays and a few bit-wise operations.

If you have any suggestions how my code could be made more readable or performant, please share your insight! Thank you very much!

*perft() results for the initial position at depth 5:*

```
a2a4: 1
a2a3: 1
b1a3: 1
b1c3: 1
b2b4: 1
b2b3: 1
c2c3: 1
c2c4: 1
d2d3: 1
d2d4: 1
e2e4: 1
e2e3: 1
f2f4: 1
f2f3: 1
g2g4: 1
g1h3: 1
g1f3: 1
g2g3: 1
h2h3: 1
h2h4: 1

Depth: 1
Total nodes: 20
Total time: 1ms/0.001s

a2a4: 20
a2a3: 20
b1a3: 20
b1c3: 20
b2b4: 20
b2b3: 20
c2c3: 20
c2c4: 20
d2d3: 20
d2d4: 20
e2e4: 20
e2e3: 20
f2f4: 20
f2f3: 20
g2g4: 20
g1h3: 20
g1f3: 20
g2g3: 20
h2h3: 20
h2h4: 20

Depth: 2
Total nodes: 400
Total time: 1ms/0.001s

a2a4: 420
a2a3: 380
b1a3: 400
b1c3: 440
b2b4: 421
b2b3: 420
c2c3: 420
c2c4: 441
d2d3: 539
d2d4: 560
e2e4: 600
e2e3: 599
f2f4: 401
f2f3: 380
g2g4: 421
g1h3: 400
g1f3: 440
g2g3: 420
h2h3: 380
h2h4: 420

Depth: 3
Total nodes: 8902
Total time: 15ms/0.015s

a2a4: 9329
a2a3: 8457
b1a3: 8885
b1c3: 9755
b2b4: 9332
b2b3: 9345
c2c3: 9272
c2c4: 9744
d2d3: 11959
d2d4: 12435
e2e4: 13160
e2e3: 13134
f2f4: 8929
f2f3: 8457
g2g4: 9328
g1h3: 8881
g1f3: 9748
g2g3: 9345
h2h3: 8457
h2h4: 9329

Depth: 4
Total nodes: 197281
Total time: 291ms/0.291s

a2a4: 217832
a2a3: 181046
b1a3: 198572
b1c3: 234656
b2b4: 216145
b2b3: 215255
c2c3: 222861
c2c4: 240082
d2d3: 328511
d2d4: 361790
e2e4: 405385
e2e3: 402988
f2f4: 198473
f2f3: 178889
g2g4: 214048
g1h3: 198502
g1f3: 233491
g2g3: 217210
h2h3: 181044
h2h4: 218829

Depth: 5
Total nodes: 4865609
Total time: 6752ms/6.752s
```

*MoveGenerator.h:*

```
#ifndef MOVEGENERATOR_H
#define MOVEGENERATOR_H

#include "Bitboard.h"
#include "globals.h"
#include "GameState.h"
#include "MagicBitboards.h"

#include <array>
#include <vector>

namespace Chess_Engine 
{
    class MoveGenerator
    {
        using NonMagicAttackTable = std::array<Bitboard, 64>; 
        using BishopAttackTable = std::array<std::array<Bitboard, 512>, 64>; 
        using RookAttackTable = std::array<std::array<Bitboard, 4096>, 64>; 

    public:
    
        MoveGenerator();
        virtual ~MoveGenerator();

        std::vector<Move> generate_legal_moves(const GameState& game_state); // returns all legal moves for a given position
        std::vector<Move> generate_pseudo_legal_moves(const GameState& game_state); // returns all pseudo-legal moves for a given position
    
    private:
            
        // checks a single move for legality and returns result
        bool check_for_legality(const GameState& game_state, Move move, BoardState board_state, const Bitboard& all_enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& king_position, const Bitboard& king_attack_paths, const Bitboard& direct_king_attackers, const Bitboard& pinned, const Bitboard& pinners, std::unordered_map<int32_t, Bitboard>* allowed_pinned_move_path_for_index, bool king_in_check); 

        bool all_attackers_captured(Move move, const Bitboard& direct_king_attackers, bool white_to_move); 
        bool all_attack_paths_blocked(Move move, const Bitboard& king_attack_paths);

        // methods for filling move vector
        void add_king_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, bool castle_short, bool castle_long);
        void add_knight_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces);
        void add_pawn_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, bool is_white_to_move, bool en_passant_possible, uint32_t en_passant_target_square);
        void add_bishop_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces);
        void add_rook_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces);

        // methods for filling threat bitboard
        void add_king_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces);
        // -> also adds knights to direct_king_attackers if necessary
        void add_knight_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, Bitboard* direct_king_attackers, const Bitboard& king_position); 
        // -> also adds pawns to direct_king_attackers if necessary
        void add_pawn_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, Bitboard* direct_king_attackers, const Bitboard& king_position, bool is_white_to_move); 
        void add_bishop_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, const Bitboard& king_position);
        void add_rook_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, const Bitboard& king_position);
        
        // returns a bitboard of all attacks threatened by the opponent (ignoring the king for sliding pieces)
        Bitboard get_enemy_attack_bitboard(const GameState& game_state, Bitboard* direct_king_attackers);

        // methods for getting king attack info for sliding pieces
        void get_bishop_king_attack_info(const GameState& game_state, const Bitboard& bishop_positions, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& king_position, Bitboard* attack_paths, Bitboard* direct_attackers, Bitboard* pinned, Bitboard* pinners);
        void get_rook_king_attack_info(const GameState& game_state, const Bitboard& bishop_positions, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& king_position, Bitboard* attack_paths, Bitboard* direct_attackers, Bitboard* pinned, Bitboard* pinners);
        
        // gets information on where the king gets attacked from and where the attackers and pinned pieces are
        void get_attack_on_king_info(const GameState& game_state, Bitboard* attack_paths, Bitboard* attackers, Bitboard* pinned, Bitboard* pinners); 

        void initialise_king_attack_table();
        void initialise_pawn_move_table_white();
        void initialise_pawn_attack_table_white();
        void initialise_pawn_move_table_black();
        void initialise_pawn_attack_table_black();
        void initialise_knight_attack_table();

        NonMagicAttackTable king_attack_table;
        NonMagicAttackTable pawn_move_table_white;
        NonMagicAttackTable pawn_attack_table_white;
        NonMagicAttackTable pawn_move_table_black;
        NonMagicAttackTable pawn_attack_table_black;
        NonMagicAttackTable knight_attack_table;

        MagicBitboards sliding_attack_generator;
    };
}
#endif
```

*MoveGenerator.cpp:*

```
#include "MoveGenerator.h"

#include "GameState.h"
#include "Bitboard.h"
#include "Move.h"
#include "globals.h"

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

namespace Chess_Engine
{

    using NonMagicAttackTable = std::array<Bitboard, 64>; 

    MoveGenerator::MoveGenerator()
    {
        // this is where the static lookup tables get initialised 
        
        // non-sliding
        initialise_king_attack_table();
        initialise_pawn_move_table_white();
        initialise_pawn_attack_table_white();
        initialise_pawn_move_table_black();
        initialise_pawn_attack_table_black();
        initialise_knight_attack_table();
    }

    MoveGenerator::~MoveGenerator()
    {
    }

    std::vector<Move> MoveGenerator::generate_legal_moves(const GameState& game_state)
    {
        std::vector<Move> pseudo_legal_moves = generate_pseudo_legal_moves(game_state);
        std::vector<Move> legal_moves;

        Bitboard attack_paths, direct_king_attackers, pinned, pinners;
        std::unordered_map<int32_t, Bitboard> allowed_pinned_move_path_for_index;

        BoardState board_state = game_state.get_board_state();
        Bitboard all_enemy_attacks = get_enemy_attack_bitboard(game_state, &direct_king_attackers);

        Bitboard king_position = game_state.is_white_to_move() ? board_state.king_position_white : board_state.king_position_black;
        bool king_in_check = all_enemy_attacks & king_position;

        get_attack_on_king_info(game_state, &attack_paths, &direct_king_attackers, &pinned, &pinners);

        // test all pseudo legal moves for legality
        for (const Move& move : pseudo_legal_moves)
        {
            if (check_for_legality(game_state, move, board_state, all_enemy_attacks, king_position, attack_paths, direct_king_attackers, pinned, pinners, &allowed_pinned_move_path_for_index, king_in_check))
            {
                legal_moves.push_back(move);
            }
        }

        return legal_moves;
    }

    bool MoveGenerator::check_for_legality(const GameState& game_state, Move move, BoardState board_state, const Bitboard& all_enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& king_position, const Bitboard& king_attack_paths, const Bitboard& direct_king_attackers, const Bitboard& pinned, const Bitboard& pinners, std::unordered_map<int32_t, Bitboard>* allowed_pinned_move_path_for_index, bool king_in_check)
    {
        int32_t from_index = move.get_from_index();
        int32_t to_index = move.get_to_index();

        bool is_king_move = Bitboard(1UL << from_index) & king_position;
        bool is_pinned = Bitboard(1UL << from_index) & pinned;
        bool white_to_move = game_state.is_white_to_move();
        int32_t flags = move.get_flags();

        // is the moving piece a king?
        if (is_king_move)   
        {   
            // is the destination square attacked by the opponent?
            if (Bitboard::is_attacked(to_index, all_enemy_attacks))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // is the king in check?
        else if (king_in_check)
        {
            // if the king is in check and the moving piece is pinned, the move is invalid
            if (is_pinned)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // in the case of a double-check, all non-king moves are unvalid
            if (direct_king_attackers.bit_count() > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // are neither all pieces attacking the king getting captured, nor all attack paths getting blocked?
            if (!(all_attackers_captured(move, direct_king_attackers, white_to_move)) && !(all_attack_paths_blocked(move, king_attack_paths)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // is the moving piece pinned?
        else if (is_pinned)
        {
            // if allowed_pinned_move_path for given origin square is not already calculated
            if (allowed_pinned_move_path_for_index->find(from_index) == allowed_pinned_move_path_for_index->end())
            {
                Bitboard allowed_pinned_move_path = 0;
                int32_t direction = 0;

                bool same_file = (king_position.get_index() % 8) == (from_index % 8);
                bool same_rank = (king_position.get_index() / 8) == (from_index / 8);

                // rook movement
                if (same_file || same_rank)
                {
                    if (same_file) // on the same file
                    {
                        direction = from_index > king_position.get_index() ? 8 : -8;
                    }
                    else // on the same rank
                    {
                        direction = from_index > king_position.get_index() ? 1 : -1;
                    }
                }
                // bishop movement
                else
                {
                    int32_t horizontal_direction = ((king_position.get_index() % 8) < (from_index % 8)) ? 1 : -1; // horizontal index shift 
                    int32_t vertical_direction = ((king_position.get_index() / 8) > (from_index / 8)) ? -8 : 8; // vertical index shift
                    direction = horizontal_direction + vertical_direction; // total shift
                }

                // contruct allowed_pinned_move_path
                for (int32_t index = king_position.get_index() + direction; !(Bitboard(1UL << (index - direction)) & pinners) ; index += direction)
                {
                    allowed_pinned_move_path |= Bitboard(1UL << index);
                }

                allowed_pinned_move_path_for_index->insert({from_index, allowed_pinned_move_path});
            }

            // if the pinned piece is moving outside of the allowed path, the move is invalid
            if (!(Bitboard(1UL << to_index) & allowed_pinned_move_path_for_index->at(from_index)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // castling
        if (move.get_flags() == Move::KINGSIDE_CASTLE)
        {
            Bitboard castling_blockers = all_enemy_attacks | game_state.get_board_state().get_all_positions();

            if (Bitboard::is_attacked(king_position.get_index() - 1, castling_blockers) || 
                Bitboard::is_attacked(king_position.get_index() - 2, castling_blockers) ||
                king_in_check)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (flags == Move::QUEENSIDE_CASTLE)
        {
            Bitboard castling_blockers = all_enemy_attacks | game_state.get_board_state().get_all_positions();

            if (Bitboard::is_attacked(king_position.get_index() + 1, castling_blockers) || 
                Bitboard::is_attacked(king_position.get_index() + 2, castling_blockers) ||
                Bitboard::is_attacked(king_position.get_index() + 3, game_state.get_board_state().get_all_positions()) ||
                king_in_check)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // make sure en-passant captures do not expose the king by capturing the last enemy piece blocking the attack (very rare)
        if (flags == Move::EN_PASSANT_CAPTURE && !((to_index % 8 == 0) || (to_index % 8 == 7))) 
        {
            Bitboard nearest_horizontal_pieces;
            int32_t capture_shift = white_to_move ? -8 : 8;

            // all pieces, except the moving pawn
            Bitboard all_pieces = board_state.get_all_positions() & ~Bitboard(1UL << from_index);

            // search to the right
            for (int32_t index = to_index + capture_shift - 1; (index % 8) != 7; --index)
            {
                if (Bitboard(1UL << index) & all_pieces)
                {
                    nearest_horizontal_pieces |= Bitboard(1UL << index);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // search to the left
            for (int32_t index = to_index + capture_shift + 1; (index % 8) != 0; ++index)
            {
                if (Bitboard(1UL << index) & all_pieces)
                {
                    nearest_horizontal_pieces |= Bitboard(1UL << index);
                    break;
                }
            }

            Bitboard enemy_rooks = white_to_move ? board_state.rook_positions_black : board_state.rook_positions_white;
            Bitboard enemy_queens = white_to_move ? board_state.queen_positions_black : board_state.queen_positions_white;
            Bitboard enemy_horizontal_attackers = enemy_rooks | enemy_queens;

            // if one nearest horizontal piece is the own king and the other is an enemy horizontal attacker, the capture exposes the king
            if ((nearest_horizontal_pieces & king_position) && (nearest_horizontal_pieces & enemy_horizontal_attackers))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool MoveGenerator::all_attackers_captured(Move move, const Bitboard& direct_king_attackers, bool white_to_move)
    {
        if (Bitboard(1UL << move.get_to_index()) & direct_king_attackers)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (move.get_flags() == Move::EN_PASSANT_CAPTURE)
        {
            int32_t capture_shift = white_to_move ? -8 : 8;
            int32_t capture_index = move.get_to_index() + capture_shift;

            if (Bitboard(1UL << capture_index) & direct_king_attackers)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool MoveGenerator::all_attack_paths_blocked(Move move, const Bitboard& king_attack_paths)
    {
        if (Bitboard(1UL << move.get_to_index()) & king_attack_paths)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    std::vector<Move> MoveGenerator::generate_pseudo_legal_moves(const GameState& game_state)
    {
        std::vector<Move> pseudo_legal_moves;

        BoardState board_state = game_state.get_board_state();
        bool white_to_move = game_state.is_white_to_move();

        Bitboard allied_pieces = white_to_move ? board_state.get_all_positions_white() : board_state.get_all_positions_black();
        Bitboard enemy_pieces = white_to_move ? board_state.get_all_positions_black() : board_state.get_all_positions_white();

        std::array<Bitboard*, 6> allied_bitboards = white_to_move ? board_state.white_bitboards : board_state.black_bitboards;

        // process king attacks
        bool castle_short = white_to_move ? game_state.get_white_castle_short() : game_state.get_black_castle_short();
        bool castle_long = white_to_move ? game_state.get_white_castle_long() : game_state.get_black_castle_long();
        Bitboard king_position = *allied_bitboards[5];
        add_king_moves(&pseudo_legal_moves, king_position, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces, castle_short, castle_long);

        // process pawn attacks
        Bitboard pawn_positions = *allied_bitboards[0];
        add_pawn_moves(&pseudo_legal_moves, pawn_positions, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces, white_to_move, game_state.is_en_passant_possible(), game_state.get_en_passant_square());

        // process knight attacks
        Bitboard knight_positions = *allied_bitboards[2];
        add_knight_moves(&pseudo_legal_moves, knight_positions, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces);

        // process bishop attacks
        Bitboard bishop_positions = *allied_bitboards[3];
        add_bishop_moves(&pseudo_legal_moves, bishop_positions, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces);

        // process rook attacks
        Bitboard rook_positions = *allied_bitboards[1];
        add_rook_moves(&pseudo_legal_moves, rook_positions, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces);

        // process queen attacks (a queen moves like rook + bishop, so she doesn't need her own method)
        Bitboard queen_attacks = *allied_bitboards[4];
        add_bishop_moves(&pseudo_legal_moves, queen_attacks, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces);
        add_rook_moves(&pseudo_legal_moves, queen_attacks, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces);

        return pseudo_legal_moves;
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_king_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, bool castle_short, bool castle_long)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = king_attack_table[from_index];

            attacks &= ~allied_pieces;
            Bitboard capture_attacks = attacks & enemy_pieces;
            Bitboard quiet_attacks = attacks & ~enemy_pieces;

            while (capture_attacks)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(capture_attacks).get_index();
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::CAPTURE));
                capture_attacks.reset_LS1B();
            }
            while (quiet_attacks)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(quiet_attacks).get_index();
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::QUIET));
                quiet_attacks.reset_LS1B();
            }

            if (castle_short)
            {
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, from_index - 2, Move::KINGSIDE_CASTLE));
            }
            if (castle_long)
            {
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, from_index + 2, Move::QUEENSIDE_CASTLE));
            }

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_knight_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = knight_attack_table[from_index];

            attacks &= ~allied_pieces;
            Bitboard capture_attacks = attacks & enemy_pieces;
            Bitboard quiet_attacks = attacks & ~enemy_pieces;

            while (capture_attacks)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(capture_attacks).get_index();
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::CAPTURE));
                capture_attacks.reset_LS1B();
            }
            while (quiet_attacks)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(quiet_attacks).get_index();
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::QUIET));
                quiet_attacks.reset_LS1B();
            }

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_pawn_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, bool is_white_to_move, bool en_passant_possible, uint32_t en_passant_target_square)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;
        NonMagicAttackTable pawn_move_table = is_white_to_move ? pawn_move_table_white : pawn_move_table_black;
        NonMagicAttackTable pawn_attack_table = is_white_to_move ? pawn_attack_table_white : pawn_attack_table_black;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();

            Bitboard moves = pawn_move_table[from_index]; // get quiet forward moves

            moves &= (~allied_pieces & ~enemy_pieces);

            int32_t move_index_shift = is_white_to_move ? 8 : -8;

            while (moves)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(moves).get_index();

                // if pawn is moving two squares
                if (to_index == (from_index + 2*move_index_shift))
                {
                    // if in between square is empty
                    if (!(Bitboard(1UL << (from_index + move_index_shift)) & Bitboard(allied_pieces | enemy_pieces)))
                    {
                        move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::DOUBLE_PAWN_PUSH));
                    }
                }
                // if pawn moves to top or bottom rank
                else if ((to_index >= 56 && to_index <= 63) || (to_index >= 0 && to_index <= 7))
                {
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::KNIGHT_PROMOTION));
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::BISHOP_PROMOTION));
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::ROOK_PROMOTION));
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::QUEEN_PROMOTION));
                }
                else
                {
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::QUIET));
                }

                moves.reset_LS1B();
            }

            Bitboard attacks = pawn_attack_table[from_index]; // get diagonal capture moves

            // en-passant
            if (en_passant_possible)
            {
                if (Bitboard(1UL << en_passant_target_square) & attacks)
                {
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, en_passant_target_square, Move::EN_PASSANT_CAPTURE));
                }
            }

            attacks &= enemy_pieces;

            while (attacks)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacks).get_index();

                if ((to_index >= 56 && to_index <= 63) || (to_index >= 0 && to_index <= 7))
                {
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::KNIGHT_PROMOTION_CAPTURE));
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::BISHOP_PROMOTION_CAPTURE));
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::ROOK_PROMOTION_CAPTURE));
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::QUEEN_PROMOTION_CAPTURE));
                }
                else
                {
                    move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::CAPTURE));
                }

                attacks.reset_LS1B();
            }

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_bishop_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = sliding_attack_generator.get_bishop_attacks(from_index, allied_pieces | enemy_pieces);

            attacks &= ~allied_pieces;
            Bitboard capture_attacks = attacks & enemy_pieces;
            Bitboard quiet_attacks = attacks & ~enemy_pieces;

            while (capture_attacks)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(capture_attacks).get_index();
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::CAPTURE));
                capture_attacks.reset_LS1B();
            }
            while (quiet_attacks)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(quiet_attacks).get_index();
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::QUIET));
                quiet_attacks.reset_LS1B();
            }

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_rook_moves(std::vector<Move>* move_list, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = sliding_attack_generator.get_rook_attacks(from_index, allied_pieces | enemy_pieces);

            attacks &= ~allied_pieces;
            Bitboard capture_attacks = attacks & enemy_pieces;
            Bitboard quiet_attacks = attacks & ~enemy_pieces;

            while (capture_attacks)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(capture_attacks).get_index();
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::CAPTURE));
                capture_attacks.reset_LS1B();
            }
            while (quiet_attacks)
            {
                int32_t to_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(quiet_attacks).get_index();
                move_list->push_back(Move(from_index, to_index, Move::QUIET));
                quiet_attacks.reset_LS1B();
            }

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_king_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = king_attack_table[from_index];

            *enemy_attacks |= attacks;

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_knight_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, Bitboard* direct_king_attackers, const Bitboard& king_position)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = knight_attack_table[from_index];

            if (attacks & king_position)
            {
                *direct_king_attackers |= Bitboard(1UL << from_index);
            }

            *enemy_attacks |= attacks;

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_pawn_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, Bitboard* direct_king_attackers, const Bitboard& king_position, bool is_white_to_move)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks;

            if (is_white_to_move)
            {
                attacks |= pawn_attack_table_black[from_index];
            }
            else
            {
                attacks |= pawn_attack_table_white[from_index];
            }

            if (attacks & king_position)
            {
                *direct_king_attackers |= Bitboard(1UL << from_index);
            }

            *enemy_attacks |= attacks;

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_bishop_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, const Bitboard& king_position)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = sliding_attack_generator.get_bishop_attacks(from_index, (allied_pieces ^ king_position) | enemy_pieces);

            *enemy_attacks |= attacks;

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::add_rook_attacks(Bitboard* enemy_attacks, const Bitboard& attacking_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, const Bitboard& king_position)
    {
        Bitboard attacking = attacking_pieces;

        while (attacking)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(attacking).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = sliding_attack_generator.get_rook_attacks(from_index, (allied_pieces ^ king_position) | enemy_pieces);

            *enemy_attacks |= attacks;

            attacking.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    Bitboard MoveGenerator::get_enemy_attack_bitboard(const GameState& game_state, Bitboard* direct_king_attackers)
    {
        Bitboard all_attacks;

        BoardState board_state = game_state.get_board_state();
        bool white_to_move = game_state.is_white_to_move();

        Bitboard allied_pieces = white_to_move ? board_state.get_all_positions_white() : board_state.get_all_positions_black();
        Bitboard enemy_pieces = white_to_move ? board_state.get_all_positions_black() : board_state.get_all_positions_white();

        Bitboard king_position = white_to_move ? board_state.king_position_white : board_state.king_position_black;

        Bitboard enemy_king_position = white_to_move ? board_state.king_position_black : board_state.king_position_white;
        add_king_attacks(&all_attacks, enemy_king_position);

        Bitboard enemy_pawn_positions = white_to_move ? board_state.pawn_positions_black : board_state.pawn_positions_white;
        add_pawn_attacks(&all_attacks, enemy_pawn_positions, direct_king_attackers, king_position, white_to_move);

        Bitboard enemy_knight_positions = white_to_move ? board_state.knight_positions_black : board_state.knight_positions_white;
        add_knight_attacks(&all_attacks, enemy_knight_positions, direct_king_attackers, king_position);

        Bitboard enemy_bishop_positions = white_to_move ? board_state.bishop_positions_black : board_state.bishop_positions_white;
        add_bishop_attacks(&all_attacks, enemy_bishop_positions, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces, king_position);

        Bitboard enemy_rook_positions = white_to_move ? board_state.rook_positions_black : board_state.rook_positions_white;
        add_rook_attacks(&all_attacks, enemy_rook_positions, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces, king_position);

        Bitboard enemy_queen_positions = white_to_move ? board_state.queen_positions_black : board_state.queen_positions_white;
        add_bishop_attacks(&all_attacks, enemy_queen_positions, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces, king_position);
        add_rook_attacks(&all_attacks, enemy_queen_positions, allied_pieces, enemy_pieces, king_position);

        return all_attacks;
    }

    void MoveGenerator::get_attack_on_king_info(const GameState& game_state, Bitboard* attack_paths, Bitboard* direct_attackers, Bitboard* pinned, Bitboard* pinners)
    {
        BoardState board_state = game_state.get_board_state();
        bool white_to_move = game_state.is_white_to_move();

        Bitboard allied_pieces = white_to_move ? board_state.get_all_positions_white() : board_state.get_all_positions_black();
        Bitboard enemy_pieces = white_to_move ? board_state.get_all_positions_black() : board_state.get_all_positions_white();

        Bitboard king_position = white_to_move ? board_state.king_position_white : board_state.king_position_black;

        Bitboard enemy_bishop_positions = white_to_move ? board_state.bishop_positions_black : board_state.bishop_positions_white;
        get_bishop_king_attack_info(game_state, enemy_bishop_positions, enemy_pieces, allied_pieces, king_position, attack_paths, direct_attackers, pinned, pinners);

        Bitboard enemy_rook_positions = white_to_move ? board_state.rook_positions_black : board_state.rook_positions_white;
        get_rook_king_attack_info(game_state, enemy_rook_positions, enemy_pieces, allied_pieces, king_position, attack_paths, direct_attackers, pinned, pinners);

        Bitboard enemy_queen_positions = white_to_move ? board_state.queen_positions_black : board_state.queen_positions_white;
        get_bishop_king_attack_info(game_state, enemy_queen_positions, enemy_pieces, allied_pieces, king_position, attack_paths, direct_attackers, pinned, pinners);
        get_rook_king_attack_info(game_state, enemy_queen_positions, enemy_pieces, allied_pieces, king_position, attack_paths, direct_attackers, pinned, pinners);
    }

    void MoveGenerator::get_bishop_king_attack_info(const GameState& game_state, const Bitboard& bishop_positions, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& king_position, Bitboard* attack_paths, Bitboard* direct_attackers, Bitboard* pinned, Bitboard* pinners)
    {
        Bitboard enemy_bishop_positions = bishop_positions;

        while (enemy_bishop_positions)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(enemy_bishop_positions).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = sliding_attack_generator.get_bishop_attacks(from_index, enemy_pieces);
            Bitboard king_attack_path;

            // if king is theoretically attacked
            if (attacks & king_position)
            {
                // calculate attack path
                int32_t horizontal_direction = ((king_position.get_index() % 8) < (from_index % 8)) ? -1 : +1; // horizontal index shift 
                int32_t vertical_direction = ((king_position.get_index() / 8) > (from_index / 8)) ? +8 : -8; // vertical index shift
                int32_t direction = horizontal_direction + vertical_direction; // total shift

                // loop through attack path and save it
                for (int32_t index = from_index + direction; index != king_position.get_index(); index += direction)
                {
                    king_attack_path |= (1UL << index);
                }

                Bitboard blockers = king_attack_path & allied_pieces; // all allied pieces blocking the path

                if (blockers.bit_count() == 0)
                {
                    *direct_attackers |= Bitboard(1UL << from_index); // add attacker to all direct attackers
                    *attack_paths |= king_attack_path; // add attack path to all attack paths
                }
                else if (blockers.bit_count() == 1)
                {
                    *pinned |= blockers; // add blocker to pinned pieces
                    *pinners |= Bitboard(1UL << from_index); // add attacker to pinning pieces
                }
            }

            enemy_bishop_positions.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }


    void MoveGenerator::get_rook_king_attack_info(const GameState& game_state, const Bitboard& rook_positions, const Bitboard& enemy_pieces, const Bitboard& allied_pieces, const Bitboard& king_position, Bitboard* attack_paths, Bitboard* direct_attackers, Bitboard* pinned, Bitboard* pinners)
    {
        Bitboard enemy_rook_positions = rook_positions;

        while (enemy_rook_positions)
        {
            int32_t from_index = Bitboard::isolate_LS1B(enemy_rook_positions).get_index();
            Bitboard attacks = sliding_attack_generator.get_rook_attacks(from_index, enemy_pieces);
            Bitboard king_attack_path;

            // if king is theoretically attacked
            if (attacks & king_position)
            {
                int32_t direction = 0;

                // calculate attack path
                if ((from_index % 8) == (king_position.get_index() % 8)) // on the same file
                {
                    if (from_index > king_position.get_index())
                    {
                        direction = -8;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        direction = 8;
                    }
                }
                else // on the same rank
                {
                    if (from_index > king_position.get_index())
                    {
                        direction = -1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        direction = 1;
                    }
                }

                // loop through attack path and save it
                for (int32_t index = from_index + direction; index != king_position.get_index(); index += direction)
                {
                    king_attack_path |= Bitboard(1UL << index);
                }

                Bitboard blockers = king_attack_path & allied_pieces; // all allied pieces blocking the path

                if (blockers.bit_count() == 0)
                {
                    *direct_attackers |= Bitboard(1UL << from_index); // add attacker to all direct attackers
                    *attack_paths |= king_attack_path; // add attack path to all attack paths
                }
                else if (blockers.bit_count() == 1)
                {
                    *pinned |= blockers; // add blocker to pinned pieces
                    *pinners |= Bitboard(1UL << from_index); // add attacker to pinning pieces
                }
            }

            enemy_rook_positions.reset_LS1B(); 
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::initialise_king_attack_table()
    {
        for (int32_t square = 0; square < 64; ++square)
        {
            Bitboard attacks;

            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 9)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[0] & Bitboard::mask_file[7]; // up -> left
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 8)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[0]; // up
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 7)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[0] & Bitboard::mask_file[0]; // up -> right
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 1)) & Bitboard::mask_file[7]; // left
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 1)) & Bitboard::mask_file[0]; // right
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 7)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[7] & Bitboard::mask_file[7]; // down -> left
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 8)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[7]; // down
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 9)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[7] & Bitboard::mask_file[0]; // down -> right

            king_attack_table[square] = attacks;
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::initialise_pawn_move_table_white()
    {
        for (int32_t square = 0; square < 64; ++square)
        {
            Bitboard attacks;

            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 8)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[0]; // up by one

            if (square <= 15 && square >= 8)
            {
                attacks |= (1UL << (square + 16)); // up by two
            }

            pawn_move_table_white[square] = attacks;
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::initialise_pawn_attack_table_white()
    {
        for (int32_t square = 0; square < 64; ++square)
        {
            Bitboard attacks;

            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 9)) & Bitboard::mask_file[7] & Bitboard::mask_rank[0]; // diagonal left
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 7)) & Bitboard::mask_file[0] & Bitboard::mask_rank[0]; // diagonal right

            pawn_attack_table_white[square] = attacks;
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::initialise_pawn_move_table_black()
    {
        for (int32_t square = 0; square < 64; ++square)
        {
            Bitboard attacks;

            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 8)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[7]; // up by one

            if (square <= 55 && square >= 48)
            {
                attacks |= (1UL << (square - 16)); // up by two
            }

            pawn_move_table_black[square] = attacks;
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::initialise_pawn_attack_table_black()
    {
        for (int32_t square = 0; square < 64; ++square)
        {
            Bitboard attacks;

            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 9)) & Bitboard::mask_file[0] & Bitboard::mask_rank[7]; // diagonal right
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 7)) & Bitboard::mask_file[7] & Bitboard::mask_rank[7]; // diagonal left

            pawn_attack_table_black[square] = attacks;
        }
    }

    void MoveGenerator::initialise_knight_attack_table()
    {
        for (int32_t square = 0; square < 64; ++square)
        {
            Bitboard attacks;

            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 17)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[0] & Bitboard::mask_rank[1] & Bitboard::mask_file[7]; // 2 up -> 1 left
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 15)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[0] & Bitboard::mask_rank[1] & Bitboard::mask_file[0]; // 2 up -> 1 right
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 10)) & Bitboard::mask_file[6] & Bitboard::mask_file[7] & Bitboard::mask_rank[0]; // 2 left -> 1 up
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 6)) & Bitboard::mask_file[6] & Bitboard::mask_file[7] & Bitboard::mask_rank[7]; // 2 left -> 1 down
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 15)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[6] & Bitboard::mask_rank[7] & Bitboard::mask_file[7];  // 2 down -> 1 left
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 17)) & Bitboard::mask_rank[6] & Bitboard::mask_rank[7] & Bitboard::mask_file[0]; // 2 down -> 1 right
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square + 6)) & Bitboard::mask_file[0] & Bitboard::mask_file[1] & Bitboard::mask_rank[0]; // 2 right -> 1 up
            attacks |= Bitboard(1UL << (square - 10)) & Bitboard::mask_file[0] & Bitboard::mask_file[1] & Bitboard::mask_rank[7]; // 2 right -> 1 down

            knight_attack_table[square] = attacks;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't expect the `MagicBitboards` class to be the problem either, but without it we can't actually run the code, which would have been useful

Comment: @harold Well for the code to run, you actually need half my codebase, I think that would be way too much for a single question.

Comment: Maybe, but now no one else can run a profiler over the code (and potential improvements), that makes it difficult to give useful advice.. For example I could suggest that `allowed_pinned_move_path_for_index` be turned into an array, but I don't *know* that that will help.

Answer (score 3):

- `check_for_legality` is indeed overcomplicated. It *seems* (can't say for sure without profiling) that blindly making the pseudo-legal move and testing for a King's exposure afterwards should be faster. Castling is a special case of course.

  In any case, a method with *11* parameters is a sure indication that something is wrong with the design.
- Legality of castling doesn't look correct. `b1` (or `b8`) square being attacked does not invalidate Queenside castling.

  Also, testing for `king_in_check` here is redundant. It is already known that king is *not* in check.
- I don't see why `add_*_moves` should care about `capture_attacks` vs `quiet_attacks`.
- `all_attack_paths_blocked` implementation is anti-idiomatic.

  ```
    if (condition) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  ```

  is a long way to say

  ```
    return condition;
  ```
- `generate_pseudo_legal_moves` feels like it should be `private`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1. I agree, do you have any suggestions on how to improve the design here? 2. You are right, `b1/b8` being attacked does not invalidate queenside castling, but my logic is correct. I just "misuse" the method `is_attacked()` a bit by passing all piece positions as threat board. Also, testing for `king_in_check` is not redundant, because castling counts as a king move, so it is not necessarily tested above.

Comment: 3. `add_*_moves` cares about whether the move is a capture or not because the created move needs to have the correct move type property. 4. `generate_pseudo_legal_moves` needs to be public, because it gets called somewhere else independently.